# Relationships for data extensions in Journey Builder and Filtering

Tags: relationships, dataextensions, journeybuilder, filters

1.) Relationships for data extensions that are configured in the contact framework within the contact builder are only applicable for consumption within the journey builder.

2.) If you intend to create filters from the data extensions then you'll need to utilize data relationships.

Isn't this double work?

**Wouldn't it be convenient to have a common place where we can create relationships which could be used for journey builder and filtering?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in the partner community and got the following response.

Contact Builder relationships are used for filtering within Journey Builder, Mobile Connect, Mobile Push, Group Connect and Ad Studio. 
They are working to bring the Contact model and Email Studio together as soon as possible.